# Given a matrix $H$, how can I find the "eigenmatrices" $E_\alpha$ such that $[H,E_\alpha]= \alpha E_\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is just an Eigenvector problem, but I'm not sure how to tackle it.

If we have instead of ordinary matrix multiplication the commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$ and instead of an eigenvector $\vec v$ we're looking for an "eigenmatrix" $E$, with eigenvalue $\alpha$.

How can I find the "eigenmatrices" $E_\alpha$ of a given matrix "H", such that $[H,E_\alpha]= \alpha E_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a given $H$, then you can do this (though with quite a bit of work) by writing up the linear map given by $A\mapsto [H,A]$ (just see what it does to some basis for the space of matrices) and doing the usual eigenvector computations.

Unfortunately, this means that you will probably be working in a very large dimension, but that is not really avoidable, since that is really where this problem "lives".